# Django Models get all models with the objects with the a ForeignKey's

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I would like to have a method which I can call and the return will be something like this (dict, list or queryset doesn't matter to me):

```
{
    'name': 'test',
    'long': '1.2345',
    'lat':  '1.2345',
    'measurements': [
             {
                'time': datetime
                'value': 3245.2
             },
             {
                'time': datetime
                'value': 3213.1
             },
             
         ]
}
```

I have the following models:

```
class Block(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    long = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=9, decimal_places=7)
    lat = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=9, decimal_places=7)

class BlockMeasurement(models.Model):
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    value = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

I could make a function that would loop through all of the Blocks and then add measurements to an array and later add the list of measurements to the dict, but there must be a nicer way to handle this.

## Update:

In the docs I saw method called *select_related()*  that would get all of je related objects. But do I have to loop through every block and get all of the measurements with *select_related()*, add them together in a dict or something? Or is there another simplier way to do this?

Comment: This is what a serializer is all about. The Django rest framework has tooling for this: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Answer (score 0):

Nicer way is to use [django serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/serialization/) as it described in docs

**UPDATE:**
I'm not sure what "correct block" means in your idea. If you need a nested structure with measurement lists included into dicts of Block data according to fk relations then [the very first example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/serialization/#serializing-data) in the docs do exactly what you need

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("json", Block.objects.all()) # json instead of xml
```

Comment: Its not really about the output. More about how to add all rows of a querysets foreign key in one output. So in the example, how to add all measurements to the correct block in one output.

Comment: I meant current instead of correct.

I just tried your solution but this will only give the output of the Model. I also need the tables that are connected with the model, by a primary key.